# Would an object with a high positive charge attract an object with a low positive charge?

Tags: electricity, electrons, voltage

I know that all charged objects attract neutral objects, but, for example, would an object with half of its electrons removed attract an object with one or two electrons removed?

Comment: Except for one special condition spheres can be made to attract if they are close enough to one another.  http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royprsa/468/2145/2829.full.pdf

Comment: sounds interesting but could you explain?

Comment: The very last sentence of the abstract states that opposite sign charges are induced on one of the spheres and so there is a net attractive force because the attractive forces between opposite charges are larger than the repulsive forces between same charges.

Answer (score 2):

No, because force between two charges is $Kq_1q_2/r^2$, with $K>0$.
When this quantity is negative, the force is attractive; when it is positive, it will be repulsive.
So, as you can see, the attractive/repulsive nature o force depends on the nature of charge and not the magnitude. So, two positive charges will always repell each other.

Comment: What if Kq1q2/r^2 is zero?

Comment: Coulomb's law is applicable for point charges. This is not the complete answer. @Jeromium294 raised a fair point. How would you explain that an uncharged body is attracted by a charged one.

Comment: If it is zero, then that means one of the particles is uncharged. Thus, the formula says that the force would be zero between them, which is as expected!